# the O(), θ() and Ω()time complexities of a code

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Please help me to find the `O()`, `θ()` and `Ω()` time complexities of the following code.

```
if(x<A) Func1(n);
else if(x<A+1000) Func2(n);
else if(x<A+5000) Func3(n);
else Func4(n);
```

Given:

```
Func1(n)=θ(n)
Func2(n)=θ(2^n)
Func3(n)=θ(logn)
Func4(n)=O(n)
Func4(n)=Ω(logn)
```

Comment: If something is in `θ(foo)`, it's also in `O(foo)` and `Ω(foo)` (in fact something is in `θ(foo)` *iff* it is in `O(foo)` and `Ω(foo)`), so you only need to find out the θ.

Comment: Is anything given about `x` ?  Is any relation given between `x` and `n` ?

Comment: no there is no relation between x and n. x is just arbitrary variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `f` be the function defined by the displayed code, and let `f₁...f₄` denote `Func1...4`.  If no information is given about the values of `x` and `A`, the most that one can conclude about `f` is that `f(n)` is bounded below by the least lower bound that applies to any of `f₁...f₄`, and bounded above by the greatest upper bound that applies to any of `f₁...f₄`.  The least lower bound of these is Ω(n), and the greatest upper bound is O(2ⁿ), so the complexity of `f(n)` is Ω(n) and O(2ⁿ).

The complexity of `f₄(n)` in the question *(as originally stated)* was not well-defined because a function that is bounded below by a multiple of `n log n` cannot be bounded above by a multiple of `n`.  However, neither of the given `f₄` bounds, O(n) and Ω(nlogn), is outside the range of  Ω(n) and O(2ⁿ).

*Edit:* With the question as revised, `f₃` is θ(logn), while `f₄` is Ω(log n) and O(n). The least lower bound over `f₁...f₄` now is  Ω(log n), whence complexity of `f(n)` is Ω(log n) and O(2ⁿ).  Absent information about `x` and `A`, there is no function `g(n)` such that constants `C₁` and `C₂` exist giving `C₁·g(n) < f(n) < C₂·g(n)` asymptotically, so no θ() bound can be stated for `f()`.

Comment: Func4(n)=Ω(logn). But what about θ()? Should it be the greatest upper bound, i.e. O(2ⁿ)?